# Creating an read only arraylist of string from inputstream

Tags: java

I have been trying to store strings from inputstream to arraylist.

Firstly I have converted inputStream to string using

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream , str);
str.toString();
```

then I am trying to store this string into arraylist as:

```
public static final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n"))));
```

It is showing **error :**

> 1. Illegal modifier for parameter list, only final is permitted
> 2. Type safety: the expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List

Please tell me where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inside the method `static` and `public` type are not permitted for the local variables Remove the type

Do like this

```
 List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n"))));
```

Comment: or just Collection<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n"))));

Comment: I have a lil doubt.If I want to return this list, will the return type of method be List<String> ?

Comment: You may use `List<String>` to avoid the `type-safety` warnings but not strict to have that type.

Comment: I have used List<String> and am getting type safety warnings nd method is saying "This method must return a result of type List<String> Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. First, keywords **static** and **public** can only be applied to class fields (if talking about data not methods), but not to local variables.

There are a few words to say about **final** keyword. In Java there are two kinds of types: primitives (int, float, double, etc) and references. If you apply final keyword to a primitive-typed variable it actually protects it from being changed.

For reference-types it's more complicated. E.g.:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

you cannot change list variable (which is a reference to actual list), but you can modify list itself. If you want to protect list from modifying, you use *unmodifiableList* method:

```
final List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Collections.unmodifiableList` you can directly pass `Arrays.asList`, as it gives you a list.
No need to wrap with `ArrayList` instance again.

Also there is no reference already to the newly created list.

You can do like this:

```
List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(str.split("\n")));
```

By `Arrays.asList` you can not add or remove elements.

By unmodifiable list you can not add, remove or modify using setter method from the internal list

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.test;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("/home/ikuser/testing.txt"));// Give Path Of the file
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize List
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            out.append(line);
            list.add(line); // Add Line in the list
        }
        reader.close();
        for(String l : list){
            System.out.println(l); //list print
        }
    }
}
```